# Order extensions in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sequence, sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extension

I have 2 extensions which need to have a specific order on a sitecollection. I already tried setting the  in ClientSideInstance.xml and also in Tenant Wide Extensions list.
Do you know other ways to order the rendering of the extensions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. There is a parameter in the `manifiest.json` file, that should allow you which extension should load before, however, it doesn't work.

Some solutions you may try:

- One of the extension to leverage the [DynamicDataProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/dynamic-data) spfx resource, and make the other spfx extension to use the subscrided data.
- One of the extension injects some code when it is loaded in the page, like addign an extra class to the `body` class, as `extYYY-loaded`. The other extension is monitoring the body attributes using a [mutationObserver](http://I%20think%20I%20heard%20there%20was%20a%20param%20to%20define%20when%20a%20extension%20should%20load%20(%20in%20which%20order%20)%20within%20a%20spfx%20bundle%20that%20includes%20multiple%20spfx%20packages,%20however,%20but%20it%20was%20not%20fully%20working.), and triggers in as soon as the atribute appears.